# Get array of matching cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a document with a sheet that contains company names and another that has a column with those same names and another row with different locations for each company. It looks similar to:

```
 Company  |   Location
Company1  |  Location1
Company1  |  Location2
Company2  |  Location1
```

Etc. I need a formula to return an array of the row numbers that match a specific company name, something like `[0, 1]` for Company1 and `[2]` for Company2. Is there a formula that can do this?

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets array handling features doesn't work in the same way. Which app are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=filter(row(A:A),A:A="Company1")
```

or

```
=filter(row(A:A),A:A=A2)
```

To get them in one cell

```
=arrayformula(left(concatenate(filter(row(A:A),A:A=A2)&","),len(concatenate(filter(row(A:A),A:A=A2)&","))-1))
```

Comment: Very close. Any way to put all the values into one cell, instead of multiple cells in the same column?

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate them. I don't know a short way of removing the final comma, so formula becomes a bit long

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MATCH` formula which would return the row number,

`=MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)`

Where A1 is the company names in your current sheet, A:A is the company names present in Sheet2 (with location). This formula returns the row number.

A point to have in mind - row number starts from A1 which would be 1 and so on.

Comment: That's definitely a good start. But is there a way for it to return all of the rows where the string occurs? So that if I'm looking for 'Compan1', it would return something like '[1, 2]'?

Comment: @CodyHarness can you update the question with how you want your output to be?

Comment: you may have to check this link, http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/